# How to open files that are in an array

Tags: php, arrays, file

So I would like to search for certain types of files in a directory and then insert those into an array followed by a loop to open them once each has been executed.

```
    <?php
    $files = glob('/home/apps/*.log');
    foreach ($files AS $logs) {
        $handle = fopen($logs[] , 'r');
        //run functions and do stuff here to file
        fclose($logs[]);
    }
    ?>
```

So it should open each file that matches the criteria and execute functions and other stuff to each file and close them once done.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

`$logs[]` should be `$logs`. You're not trying to add to the logs file as an array your only reading logs as a log.

Comment: While this is correct, it's more of a comment, and this question should be closed because it's simply a typographical error. I highly doubt anyone will ever have this same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files = glob('/home/apps/*.log');
foreach ($files AS $logs) {

$myfile = fopen($logs, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
}
    //run functions and do stuff here to file
    fclose($logs);
}
?>
```